# How to create a Auth system to Whatsapp-api.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, node-modules, whatsapp

I'm creating a chatbot to WhatsApp via JavaScript and Node using Whatsapp-api (https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/tree/main), I'm having a problem when two users try to answer at the same time, because if someone is in the Flow and other person texts during the Flow the code will take that information into the variable, and confusing the rest of the Flow.

Here´s my complete code

```
// Invocamos o leitor de qr code
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const { Client, Buttons, List, MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js'); // Mudança Buttons
const client = new Client();
// entao habilitamos o usuario a acessar o serviço de leitura do qr code
client.on('qr', qr => {
qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});
// apos isso ele diz que foi tudo certin
client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Tudo certo! WhatsApp conectado.');
});

client.initialize();

let aguardandoNome = false;
let aguardandoNome_empresa = false;
let aguardandoPrimeiro_contato = false;
let aguardandoTelefone = false;
let aguardandoProduto = false;
let nome;
let nome_empresa;
let telefone;
let primeira_producao;
let produto;
let tempoResposta = 120000; // Tempo limite de 2 minutos em milissegundos
let atendimentoConcluido = false; // novo booleano para verificar se o atendimento foi concluído
let timeoutExecutado = true; // novo booleano para verificar se o timeout já foi executado


client.on('message', async msg => {
  // Define a função para ser executada após o tempo limite de resposta

  let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    // Limpa as variáveis de aguardando
    aguardandoNome = false;
    aguardandoNome_empresa = false;
    aguardandoPrimeiro_contato = false;
    aguardandoTelefone = false;
    aguardandoProduto = false;

    // Verifica se o atendimento já foi concluído antes de enviar a mensagem de timeout
    if (!atendimentoConcluido && !timeoutExecutado) {
      client.sendMessage(msg.from, 'O tempo limite para resposta foi atingido. Por favor, reinicie o processo digitando "INICIAR".');
      timeoutExecutado = true; 
    }
  }, tempoResposta);

    if (msg.body.toLowerCase() === 'iniciar') {
        clearTimeout(timeout); // Limpa o timeout anterior
        atendimentoConcluido = false;
        timeoutExecutado = false; 
        const chat = await msg.getChat();
        await client.sendMessage(msg.from, 'Me informa seu nome por gentileza?');

        aguardandoNome = true;
    } else if (aguardandoNome) {
        clearTimeout(timeout); // Limpa o timeout anterior
        nome = msg.body;
        await client.sendMessage(msg.from, `Prazer, ${nome}! Sou o Assistente Virtual da Gset Gráfica\nEu preciso de alguns dados antes de continuarmos.`);
        await client.sendMessage(msg.from, 'Poderia me Informar o Nome da sua Empresa?');

        aguardandoNome = false;
        aguardandoNome_empresa = true;
    } else if (aguardandoNome_empresa) {
        clearTimeout(timeout); // Limpa o timeout anterior
        nome_empresa = msg.body;
        await client.sendMessage(msg.from, 'Certo, Qual Seu Telefone para contato com DDD (via Whatsapp)?');
        
        aguardandoNome_empresa = false;
        aguardandoTelefone = true;
    } 
     else if (aguardandoTelefone) {
        clearTimeout(timeout); // Limpa o timeout anterior
        telefone = msg.body;
        await client.sendMessage(msg.from, 'Você já é nosso cliente ou é seu primeiro contato conosco? Chegou a nos enviar algum e-mail, solicitação diretamente pelo nosso site além do Whatsapp?\n\n 1- Sim, Já produzi materiais com vocês.\n2- Não, mas já entrei em contato por outros meios\n3- Não, esse é o primeiro contato.');        
        
        aguardandoTelefone = false;
        aguardandoPrimeiro_contato = true;

    } else if (aguardandoPrimeiro_contato) {
        clearTimeout(timeout); // Limpa o timeout anterior
        primeira_producao = msg.body;

        switch (primeira_producao) {
            case '1':
              primeira_producao = 'Sim, Já produzi materiais com vocês.';
              break;
            case '2':
              primeira_producao = 'Não, mas já entrei em contato por outros meios';
              break;
            case '3':
              primeira_producao = 'Não, esse é o primeiro contato.';
              break;
            default:
              primeira_producao = 'Inseriu um valor inválido, Verificar com o cliente.'
              break;
          }


        await client.sendMessage(msg.from, 'Quais são os produtos que tem interesse de produzir conosco? Caso queira ver o nosso catálogo : https://www.gset.com.br/produtos/');

        aguardandoPrimeiro_contato = false;
        aguardandoProduto = true;
    } else if (aguardandoProduto) {
        clearTimeout(timeout); // Limpa o timeout anterior
        produto = msg.body;
        await client.sendMessage(msg.from, `Muito Obrigado ${nome}! Estaremos encaminhando seu contato para um de nossos vendedores fazer seu atendimento personalizado.`);
        await client.sendMessage('5511939510866@c.us', `Informações Coletadas\nNome: ${nome}\nNome da Empresa: ${nome_empresa}
        \nTelefone: ${telefone}\nPrimeira Produção: ${primeira_producao}\nProduto: ${produto}`);
        
        atendimentoConcluido = true;
        aguardandoProduto = false;
    }
  
});
```

The flow is working, but I need to make more than 1 conversation in the flow work at the same time.

I tried implementing a timeout function but is not working as I wanted, I wanted that the timeout cleared every time the person answered a question but I think there might be a logic error somewhere i did not find.